# Angular 8 and setting observable inside subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In the first component, I have a variable `this.products` that is a result of a subscription to an observable(s). Since getting this variable's value involves a lot of swithcMap-ing and similar stuff, I don't want to repeat all the convoluted logic in the second component, where I need this result as well (and not only in html template). Is it ok to do the following for this purpose? It works fine, but I have never seen such a pattern before and was wondering if something might be wrong with it.

a) First component

```
this.getProducts().lotsOfSwitchMapping
    .subscribe((products) => 
        {this.products = products; 
        this.setNiceItems.next(products)});
```

b) Second component

```
this.getNiceItems()
    .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
```

So `this.items` and `this.products` are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely fine and a common pattern in software engineering simply known as DRY (dont repeat yourself). To be more Angular specific you should definitely outsource your logic into a service and from there on out just subscribe to the observable in the service from your components such that you have some pattern like:

```
this.myItemsService
  .itemsChanged()      // where this returns the observable with all your switch mappings
  .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
```

Comment: I was thinking about a service, but first needed to make sure that I'm not completely offtrack - I know that now, so thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, using a service is the recommended approach for all of your `switchMap`ing.

Here is an example from one of my services:

**In a service**

```
  productsWithCategory$ = combineLatest([
    this.products$,
    this.productCategoryService.productCategories$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, categories]) =>
      products.map(product => ({
        ...product,
        price: product.price * 1.5,
        category: categories.find(c => product.categoryId === c.id).name,
        searchKey: [product.productName]
      }) as Product)
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Each component can then subscribe to this Observable. And since it uses `shareReplay(1)`, each subscriber will get the same emitted items.

In my code, I use `asyncPipe` in both of my components to do the subscribe/unsubscribe automatically.

I have example code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS

This video may also be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @DeborahK for the very useful and well explained reply! I've never heard about shareReplay(1), I will for sure take a look at it as well as your links! I'd give you the green checkmark, but null1 replied sooner. Cheers and thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The many switch maps are kind of too much business logic in a component. I recommend to do this switchmapping in the service and you can use that service method in both components.

```
// service
public getNiceProducts(): Observable<Products[]> {
  return this.getProducts().pipe(
    // lots of switchMapping
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll do that!